# cordova setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, cordova, settimeout

I'm encountering a problem with setTimeout, and I can't figure out why.

I'm using cordova, and the setTimeout function leads to curious comportment.

```
app.displayData = function(device) {
    app.readThermometer(device);
    app.readAccelerometer(device);
    app.readHumidity(device);
    app.readMagnetometer(device);
    //setTimeout(app.displayData(device), 5000);
};
```

This is executed once.

```
app.displayData = function(device) {
    app.readThermometer(device);
    app.readAccelerometer(device);
    app.readHumidity(device);
    app.readMagnetometer(device);
    setTimeout(app.displayData(device), 5000);
};
```

This is executed many times, but way faster than once every 5 seconds. It is a problem for me because it prevent jQuery from executing correctly. (Never getting the dom modification expected)

What am I missing? If it is a bug in cordova, do you know other way to delay code execution in javascript?

Comment: why do you want to delay code execution? What do you want to do? The second code will run **infinitely** as it is a recursive call. You need to use the setTimeout call outside app.displayData

Comment: yes, I know. It's my purpose to make it run infinitely :).
I'm getting a continuous flow of data, and i'm trying to update them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling the function `app.displayData` directly

```
setTimeout(app.displayData(device), 5000);
```

Try the following instead

```
setTimeout(function () {
    app.displayData(device);
}, 5000);
```

And another alternative if you prefer [Function.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
setTimeout(app.displayData.bind(app, device), 5000);
```